# How to calculate mean after groupby and applying in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to calculate mean(over time which is 5 minute interval) after counting '01''s. What is the best way to do it?

I have aggregated data which is recorded in 5 minute interval. And I would like to calculate mean over the time. Here's the sample dataset.

```
           captureTime    id           digits
0  2017-06-26 09:00:00  4015  558460648326103043    
1  2017-06-26 09:05:00  4015   13721946658181148   
2  2017-06-26 09:10:00  4015  288298648959188992    
3  2017-06-26 09:15:00  4015   27023247031744576    
4  2017-06-26 09:20:00  4015     435887716434584   
5  2017-06-26 09:25:00  4015          2147614720   
6  2017-06-26 09:00:00  4014  558451851700273155    
7  2017-06-26 09:05:00  4014   13721941188808728    
8  2017-06-26 09:10:00  4014  288263395867623424    
9  2017-06-26 09:15:00  4014   18016047776938080    
10 2017-06-26 09:20:00  4014     145547927225032    
11 2017-06-26 09:25:00  4014          3221356544
```

Here's my current code:

```
df_onoff = df_sample.groupby('id')['digits'].apply(lambda nums: "%d" % ', '.join(format(n%2**60,'060b') for n in nums).count('01')).reset_index(name='onoff')
```

And here's the output of df_onoff:

```
0    34
1    36
```

Comment: So are you looking for a better solution than the one you have?

Comment: I see your output but I am confused as to what you want exactly. Is the output not what you want?

Comment: @tiba I didn't calculate mean yet.

Comment: @BenT I have aggregated value as output, but I don't have mean value afterwards yet.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused as to what you want exactly and where the '01's come into this problem. Maybe you can make your question more clear about what exactly you need. A first step may be to group your data in the time format and then take the mean.

```
df_sample.groupby('captureTime').mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

Like others, I am a little confused about what you want exactly.

Your output is the sum of `01` code for each group of `id`, instead of mean.  You have put too many expression in your last statement, it is a little hard to understand. Why not make it simple and clear?

You could first preprocess the data:

(1) INPUT

```
data=[
    ['2017-06-26 09:00:00',4015,558460648326103043],
    ['2017-06-26 09:05:00',4015,13721946658181148],
    ['2017-06-26 09:10:00',4015,288298648959188992],
    ['2017-06-26 09:15:00',4015,27023247031744576],
    ['2017-06-26 09:20:00',4015,435887716434584],
    ['2017-06-26 09:25:00',4015,2147614720],
    ['2017-06-26 09:00:00',4014,558451851700273155],
    ['2017-06-26 09:05:00',4014,13721941188808728],
    ['2017-06-26 09:10:00',4014,288263395867623424],
    ['2017-06-26 09:15:00',4014,18016047776938080],
    ['2017-06-26 09:20:00',4014,145547927225032],
    ['2017-06-26 09:25:00',4014,3221356544]
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['captureTime', 'id', 'digits'])
# convert datetime
df['captureTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.captureTime)
"""
```

(2) Count `'01'` for the `digits`

```
df['counts01'] = df.digits.apply(
                 lambda x:format(x%2**60,'060b').count('01'))
# output
           captureTime    id              digits  counts01
0  2017-06-26 09:00:00  4015  558460648326103043         8
1  2017-06-26 09:05:00  4015   13721946658181148         9
2  2017-06-26 09:10:00  4015  288298648959188992         4
3  2017-06-26 09:15:00  4015   27023247031744576         5
4  2017-06-26 09:20:00  4015     435887716434584         8
5  2017-06-26 09:25:00  4015          2147614720         2
6  2017-06-26 09:00:00  4014  558451851700273155         8
7  2017-06-26 09:05:00  4014   13721941188808728         8
8  2017-06-26 09:10:00  4014  288263395867623424         4
9  2017-06-26 09:15:00  4014   18016047776938080         4
10 2017-06-26 09:20:00  4014     145547927225032         8
11 2017-06-26 09:25:00  4014          3221356544         2
```

Now you can apply any kind aggregation function.

(1) If you want to the mean value for each `id`:

```
df.groupby('id')['counts01'].mean()
#output
id
4014    5.666667
4015    6.000000
```

For your last statement, the equvanient is:

```
In [27]: df.groupby('id')['counts01'].sum()
Out[27]: 
id
4014    34
4015    36
Name: counts01, dtype: int64
```

Obviously, it is sum for each `id` group.

(2) I don't understand what do you mean 'I would like to calculate mean over the time'. If you want to do aggregation over time, you could first generate a time series (`pd.date_range`) then group by this time series.

Thanks.

Comment: The reason that I need to apply sum then mean is the the following. Say we have 0110, 1000, 1110. Since each digit is an event, I will concatenate all digits 011010001110 then count '01' otherwise I lose '01' in between 0110 and 1110. Likewise, if I do not concatenate 1000 and 1110, I will lose one '01' in between. Sum of '01' count should be 3 and average should be 1.